# What is difference between Dialog.setContentView( View ) & AlertDialog.setView( View )

Tags: android, user-interface, customdialog

I'm working on creating a custom dialog to get input from the user. I've noticed that when I use an `AlertDialog` I can add widgets such as an `EditText` to the `AlertDialog` using `setView()` method. I'm looking into customizing `AlertDialog` and noticed that `Dialog` has a method `setContentView()`. In the subclass of `AlertDialog` I could use either `setContentView()` or `setView()`.

One difference I've noticed is when I use `setView()` on an `AlertDialog`, I can see Positive & Negative buttons.  In my subclass of `AlertDialog`, using `setContentView()` I don't get the Positive & Negative buttons.

Can anyone explain other differences?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use "setContentView()" with AlertDialog.

Comment: Actually you can.  Since AlertDialog is a subclass of Dialog, AlertDialog inherits all of Dialog's methods including Dialog.setContentView()

Comment: I have tried it you'll get this error 
The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder :)

Comment: You can use it with `AlertDialog` but not with `AlertDialog.Builder`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If I undesrstood it correctly, `setContentView` inflates the entire Dialog window with your custom layout. Title, icon, buttons... nothing remains. `setView` on the other hand sets the layout of the view between the buttons and the title.

[image: See image]

Comment: I assume you meant setContentView ?

Answer (score 2):

setContentView is AlertDialog' father class method, it means all the dialog windows, and setView is AlertController method, in AlertDialog windows view, there are topPanel，contentPanel，buttonPanel.setView only set customView to contentpanel.

Answer (score 0):

BTW you can also call the AlertDialogs setView method, which seems to also remove the extra "spacing" around the view.

void setView(View view, int viewSpacingLeft, int viewSpacingTop, int viewSpacingRight, int viewSpacingBottom)

like this.

alertDialog.setView(myView,0,0,0,0);

Comment: i have read the same in the Android Reference, but it does not seem to work for me; it would only recognize setView(myview); Do you know how to make it use setView(View view, int viewSpacingLeft, int viewSpacingTop, int viewSpacingRight, int viewSpacingBottom); ??