# Views not found for Alert Dialog in fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I am trying to populate an Alert Dialog (with a layout file having an EditText & Button) **within a fragment** of Activity.
The components are not being found by calling **findViewById()** in the **fragment's** corresponding **class**. I have written this code inside the class :

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(context); 
    View v=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_alert_dialog,null);
    final EditText txtAddNew=v.findViewById(R.id.txtAddNew);                //null
    final TextView txtErr = v.findViewById(R.id.txtErr);                    //null
    Button btnAdd=v.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);                              //null
```

I think the problem raises from this line of code:

```
 View v=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_alert_dialog,null);
```

The alertDialog XML code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtAddNew"
        android:hint="Category name"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtErr"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:text="Add Category" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone find what the actual problem is? Thanks!

Comment: First of all add : `builder.setView(v)`;

Comment: Could you paste the full code of your fragment?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2016562/gabriele-mariotti still the same

Comment: show the `layout_alert_dialog.xml`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko please read the new edit

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct
Do something like this :

```
LayoutInflater layout = LayoutInflater.from(this);
final View view = layout.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
dialog.setView(view);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: this won't help. You don't need to set a view somewhere to use `findViewById()` on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());    
alertBuilder.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_alert_dialog,null));
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertBuilder.create();
EditText txtAddNew = alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtAddNew);
TextView txtErr = alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtErr);
Button btnAdd = alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: The components are still null. Actually I am populating the AlertDialog from a fragment's corresponding class.

Comment: did you used the context and layout correctly, there were mistakes in my code posted earlier.

Comment: Since you are in a fragment, try using getActivity() instead the context.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dialog.setContentView(v)`

See the difference between `setView(v)` and `setContentView(v)` here:
[What is difference between Dialog.setContentView( View ) & AlertDialog.setView( View )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040883/what-is-difference-between-dialog-setcontentview-view-alertdialog-setview)

Comment: Please note that builder doesn't has a method called setContentView(). it should be AlertDialog.

Comment: The exception changed from NullPointer to this:

Comment: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:398)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:251)
        at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:437)

Comment: this won't help. You don't need to set a view somewhere to use `findViewById()` on it.

Comment: I am trying to put validation on the EditText in the alert dialog and thus I need to access the EditText by findViewById()